# Fails to Parse query, but running through PMA is a success

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-mysqlidb

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE users_login SET LastLogin= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME()) WHERE Username=?
```

This fails when I'm passing this into my PHP MySQLI Query Construct. But running this through PMA Query:

```
UPDATE users_login SET LastLogin= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME()) WHERE Username='Sophie'
```

I have no idea why this is failing.

Error Message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' ', CURTIME())) WHERE Username='Shophie'' at line 1

Exact Code is as followed:

```
  $Update_Parameter = array($_POST['Username']);

        $Database->rawQuery("UPDATE users_login SET LastLogin = CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME() )"
            ,$Update_Parameter);
```

I'm outsourcing to a MySQLi Wrapper for what I thought was an easier method for queries. https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Comment: can we see the error message please?

Comment: what do you mean parse query?

Comment: can you show also your `$query` variable definition in your php code and try to `echo` it before executing the query?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how rawQuery actually works, but really the MySQLi bindings are good, you should embrace them, could you show me $_POST["Username"] too please, it it's just "sophie" how does it turn array("Sophie") into where Username = 1, also try putting username in `<--backtick, that thing above tab, use this for tables and fields where the name is ambiguous (I'm thinking username might bey a keyword, I don't think it is, but I have no other ideas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the mysqli wrapper class you are using.

In method `MysqliDb::rawQuery()` there is this line of code:

```
$this->_query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

which will turn your query string

```
UPDATE users_login SET LastLogin= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME()) WHERE Username=?
```

into this:

```
UPDATE users_login SET LastLogin= CONCAT(CURDATE(), &#39; &#39;, CURTIME()) WHERE Username=?
//the single quotes now become &#39;                ^^^^^ ^^^^^
```

And then this string is passed to `mysqli::prepare()`, causing a syntax error.

I suggest you use a more mature library if you are doing serious job.

Answer (score 2):

If you look carefully in the error there are three ) for some reason, not sure why you'd have to post more, but yes,

```
 CURTIME())) 
 UPDATE users_login SET LastLogin= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME()) WHERE Username='Sophie'
```

Where did it come from?

Comment: You're going to have to post more code, if you copied and pasted the error messages there's an extra ) in there, and I don't know where from.

Comment: Probably an unorthadox method.. But for absolute proof that this is what i'm doing: https://join.me/192-023-432

Comment: Please resend the skype?